# Is it possible to do a datapump import with a different user than did the export?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have one db dump below is the log file for that dump

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  system/******** PARALLEL=1 SCHEMAS=tmsmv DUMPFILE=tmsmv-20120706.dmp LOGFILE=tmsmv-20120706.log 
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 146.1 MB
...........
```

I want to restore this dump using another user tmsmv using below command:

```
sql>conn / as sysdba
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DUMP_DIR AS '/home/..../';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DUMP_DIR TO tmsmv;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SYS.DUMP_DIR TO EXP_FULL_DATABASE;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SYS.DUMP_DIR TO IMP_FULL_DATABASE;
```

And then importing with:

```
impdp tmsmv/***** schemas=TMSMV directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=tmsmv-20120706.dmp
```

While restoring I am facing below error message:

```
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 475
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does the DUMP_DIR exist? Is it writable by the user you're running the `impdp` as? Does the log file already exist, and can you specify a different one on the command line?

Comment: yes the dump is exist and it has write permissions,and i also tested like

impdp tmsmv/* NOLOGFILE=Y schemas=TMSMV directory=DUMP_DIR dumpfile=tmsmv-20120706.dmp

in this case i got below error message


ORA-39001: invalid argument value

ORA-39000: bad dump file specification

ORA-31640: unable to open dump file 

"/home/....../tmsmv-20120706.dmp" for read

ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status

Linux Error: 13: Permission denied

Additional information: 3

Comment: not readable by user means db user or Linux user?
As a linux user i gave all permissions to that folder.

Comment: how to make my file readable by oracle owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Oracle can't read the `.dmp` file, because it's under another user's home directory. Oracle has to be able to read it, not the Linux user you're running the `impdp` command as. (Contrary to my earlier misleading comments!)

Assuming the two users are in different groups, you may need to make the `.dmp` file world-readable:

```
chmod o+r /home/..../tmsmv-20120706.dmp
```

And usually all directories in the path need to be world-readable and world-executable:

```
chmod o+rx /home/..../
```

If you wanted the log file to be created, it would be need to be writable too (`chmod o+rwx`). If it's in a subdirectory of your home directory, you might need to do this to all intermediate levels.

But relaxing permissions on your home directory can be a problem, so you might be better off using a directory somewhere else. Or leave the file where `expdp` put it, and grant permissions on that `DIRECTORY` object to `tmsmv` instead.